# Limit Maximum Weight in Cart in Opencart 2.0.3.1

Tags: opencart2.x

I am using opencart 2.0.3.1

I want to restrict the Maximum Total order to 35 KG (35000 GM)

How to restrict and alert on View Cart Page and Disable the checkout if all product collective weight is greater than 35 KG

Answer (score 0):

I assume your default Product Weight is `KG`.

In `catalog/controller/checkout/checkout.php` add this function inside class `ControllerCheckoutCheckout`

```
public function checkCartWeight($allwed_weight,$error_message){
    $cart = $this->cart->getProducts();
    $cart_weight = array_sum(array_column($cart, 'weight'));
    if($allwed_weight<$cart_weight){
        $this->session->data['error'] = $error_message;
        $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('checkout/cart'));
    }
}
```

Now you can call the `checkCartWeight($allwed_weight,$error_message)` in your `index()`

```
$allwed_weight = 35;
$error_message = "Cart Weight limit is $allwed_weight KG";
$this->checkCartWeight($allwed_weight,$error_message);
```